# sudo apt-get update fails with File has unexpected size (14696 != 14700)

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, update-manager

Doing

```
sudo  apt-get update
```

gives

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ML: No address associated with hostname
Hit:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:6 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [597 kB]
Get:7 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,546 kB]
Get:8 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [281 kB]
Get:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.7 kB]
Get:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.7 kB]
Get:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.7 kB]
Get:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.7 kB]
Ign:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:14 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.7 kB]
Err:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  File has unexpected size (14696 != 14700). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:14700 [weak]
   - SHA256:9fc3c84c15919a454ddabcb7880bc47add42e5da77ed1533335e15e9d2998182
   - SHA1:a54761dbd2b1fe027fe2e655c0d02dc763406afa [weak]
   - MD5Sum:da894ea9b60f39aba01c96a220bcd5e2 [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 01 Feb 2022 15:14:58 +0000
Get:14 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [20.1 kB]
Err:14 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata

Get:15 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,484 B]
Hit:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:18 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Fetched 1,484 B in 1s (2,161 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz  File has unexpected size (14696 != 14700). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:14700 [weak]
    - SHA256:9fc3c84c15919a454ddabcb7880bc47add42e5da77ed1533335e15e9d2998182
    - SHA1:a54761dbd2b1fe027fe2e655c0d02dc763406afa [weak]
    - MD5Sum:da894ea9b60f39aba01c96a220bcd5e2 [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 01 Feb 2022 15:14:58 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have no idea what went wrong, and found no clue as to what do do.

I really don't want to have to reinstall everything again.

Comment: "Mirror sync in progress?" Wait 15 minutes, then try again.

Comment: @mikewhatever after over an hour, still the same. Will ping this tomorrow if persists

Comment: Please try main server or another mirror.

Comment: I agree with what's already provided; ie. instead of using your current `mirror.isoc.org.il` (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.isoc.org.il-archive) use another found on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors (or use the main archive/server)

Comment: Wait a few hours, sometimes a day, then try again.  A lot of times mirrors can be slow to finish updating, and will update at a later point if they're configured right.  If this continues to fail, I would fall back to `archive.ubuntu.com` and use the default archives instead of your country mirrors.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what's already provided via comments by @mikewhatever or @nobody

Instead of using your current `mirror.isoc.org.il`

use another found on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors (or use the main [archive/server](http://archive.ubuntu.com/))

If you don't want to change your sources/mirror; you'll need to raise a ticket with your current [mirror/archive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.isoc.org.il-archive) so they can look at it and fix it.  Chances are though; the issue will have resolved itself (*next sync will almost certainly fix it*) before they actually get around to looking at the issue.

Comment: The alternative NOT mentioned here is "be patient and wait for the mirrors to finish syncing".  You get the error that OP mentioned MOST FREQUENTLY during a sync process.

Comment: I thought that was *implied* with the "*Chances are though; the issue will have resolved itself (next sync will almost certainly fix it) before they actually get around to looking at the issue.*"  but my intent isn't always as *obvious* as it should be...

Comment: Please specify *how* to use another mirror so I can accept the answer.

Comment: A great explanation on how to edit /etc/sources.list on Debian and Ubuntu https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372736/how-to-edit-sources-list-as-root-under-debian-9 and a a complete tutorial: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/ubuntu-sources-list-editing-guide/

Comment: If using Lubuntu, have you tried looking in the manual?  ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/4/4.3/software_sources.html  (*link currently shows 20.04 manual link*) displays in the first picture a *dropdown* for "Download from"  though selection is from 579 *current* mirrors listed in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors but may not be all.   This detail can be changed many ways though.  It's the same with other desktops too, just different menu options.